# Why does question mark get interpreted as "z" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why does this line output "z" instead of "?"

$ ruby -e 'puts %x[ echo #{"?"} ]'

Suppose the expression inside the #{...} is a variable that may have the value of "?". How should I modify this script so that the question mark is outputted instead of "z"?

(Please forgive the title of this question -- I don't yet understand what is going on here well enough to provide a more descriptive title.)

Comment: What OS is this?  I can't reproduce on Windows, I'm wondering if your shell is doing something funky.

Answer (score 7):

It's not ruby, it's your shell.

Many shells expand the ? character to match a single character in command line arguments.
It's useful, if you have a bunch of files name tempA,temp1,tempB,...,temp9 that you want to delete, but you don't want to delete 'temple'

```
% rm temp?
```

So I'm guessing you have a file or directory in your working directory named 'z', and the ? matches that, so it gets replaced by the shell.

Normally, when inside single quotes (like your ruby script) it wouldn't get expanded, but since you're passing the question mark to a shell command, it gets expanded there.

```
% ruby -e 'puts %x[ echo ? ]'
z
%
```

Should show you the same behaviour.

Also, if you touch a couple other single character filenames like a b c d, those should show up too:

```
% touch a b c
% ruby -e 'puts %x[ echo ? ]'
a b c z
%
```

If you want to avoid this when calling exterior shell commands from within ruby, you'll have to escape any strings you pass out.  For most purposes `String#inspect` should give a good enough escaping.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't?

```
irb(main):001:0> puts %x[echo #{"?"}]
?
=> nil
```

Using #{} will give you the value of any variables inside - I'm not sure why you're using it instead of

```
puts %x[echo "?"]
```

or just

```
puts '?'
```